# what is ril and how can it help me to read low level info.?

Tags: android, internal, ril

I'm beginner in android and I want to read low level info. like RSCP, CQI, RAC and BCCH.

Some people said That use the internal of the API can help me doing that.

I tried to learn about RIL but it was difficult to me because there is no full answer in a certain page or file.

Please give me a way to know how can I read low level info. from modem.

Answer (score 0):

RIL means Radio Interface Layer which is a bridge between Android framework and baseband. The RSCP, CQI, RAC and BCCH are under baseband protocol. Thus you can't see these information in RIL. These information need baseband provider to provide some tool to capture baseband information. Different baseband provider has different solution. So it depends on which baseband you use.

Comment: What is baseband provider? Could u provide me some of these solution.

Comment: you can reference Manufacturers in [Wiki Baseband Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband_processor).

Answer (score 0):

Radio Interface Layer: It is the bridge between Android phone framework services and the hardware. It consist of :

RIL Daemon:- The RIL Daemon initializes the Vendor RIL, processes all communication from Android telephony services and dispatches calls to the Vendor RIL as solicitated commands. RILD will be initialized during the Android system start up. Each vendor RIL has RIL_Init function.

Vendor RIL:- It is a library specific to each modem. The radio-specific vendor RIL of ril.h that processes all communication with radio hardware and dispatches calls to the RIL Daemon(rild) through unsolicited commands.

Android Telephony framework has one interface file Ril.java which keeps track of each incoming/outgoing request that has been sent/receive to RIL.It basically forms socket connection wih RIL daemon. RIL daemon links framework to vendor Ril.Each mobile vendor will have their own implementation of vendor RIl and available in .so(shared library).The design and implementation of vendor ril depends upon the modem used.

Initialisation:- When power on,phone process starts and android telephony framework is initialized,Framework makes socket connection to ril damon ,the ril damon finds the path of vendor ril library from system properties and loads vendor ril in form of.so library. The vendor ril is first intialized by calling its RIL_INIT method. The ril daemon part of RIL calls RIL_REGISTER to provide reference of each vendor ril functions to the telephony frmaework.

More information:- https://wladimir-tm4pda.github.io/porting/telephony.html https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/ril